# Sound analyzer for linux

Tags: sound

I have a big (8 hours) audio recording. How can I analyze it? I would probably like to see waves, so I could see when some abnormal noise appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're looking for a program like Audacity. There are others out there, but Audacity will allow you to zoom in on certain sections of the wave and see if there is any abnormal sectors etc.